# Box2d collision beginContant occurrs more than once

Tags: box2d, collision

Based on box2d docs and tutorials found in the Internet (best one here http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy) I assume that collision event handler beginContact should happen only once per collision.

But what I experience is that in some cases (I could not narrow this down to something particular so far) beginContact is being called more than once.

Particular example:

```
1st fixture is a box, belongs to static body and is a sensor

2nd fixture (which is also player body in 2d game I'm building) 
is a polygon, belongs to dynamic body and is not a sensor.

Both are large enough so in debug mode it is absolutely clear 
when these fixtures start to overlap and when they part. 

Result is - while player body fixture passes through static sensor, 
beginContact is called 3-4 times or more while fixtures keep oveplapping. 
Velocity is moderate (fixtures keep overlapping for a whole second and more).
```

Do I miss something in the docs? Is there some way around this maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have found an answer or at least a workaround. Maybe it will helpful to somebody.

Polygon fixture in question was actually a ChainShape. And it seems that contact is being initiated in this case for each link of the chain. Switching to regular PolygonShape solved the problem.

I think this is the part of the manual that describes the case:

```
Contacts are objects created by Box2D to manage collision between two fixtures. If the fixture has children, such as a chain shape, then a contact exists for each relevant child.
```

Answer (score 1):

Are there other fixtures in the world, apart from just those two? Are you checking to be sure the BeginContact event is really for those two fixtures? Is there anything about this "3-4 times" behavior that would make you suspect that the BeginContact might be for other fixtures, and not the static sensor?

My guess is, your player is moving over a ground surface made from multiple fixtures, and you are seeing the BeginContact event between the player and the ground fixtures.

Comment: Yes, those two are the only fixtures around - they are the player and a bonus hanging in the air. I have found out that the issue was related to fixtureShape - I used ChainShape to get advantge of ghost vertices (btw thanks for a great tutorial on those) and that seems to produce beginContact per each chain link. I've added simple PolygonShape fixture to the player body and that works ax needed - one beginContact call per collision.